# How to prove non correlation (orthogonality)?

Tags: correlation, pca

How can I check the orthogonality of one variable to any single and any **combination** of other variables?

Suppose you have 10 variables (called A to J)  and you want to prove that variable A is not correlated with any single and any combination of variables B to J.
One option would be to measure the "direct" correlation between A and each of the nine variables (B to J) via for example Spearman rho. However this approach would not look for combinations. For example, if A = B x C, then A will result with a very low rho to both B and C even if it is exactly their simple combination. Maybe I can use PCA but I am not sure. Help!

Comment: Regressing $A$ on the other variables using least squares solves this problem directly and easily.

Comment: shall I look at the pvalue? So, if the result is that 3 out of the 9 variables have a pvalue minor than 0.05, shall I understand that A is not orthogonal to a combination of that 3 variables?

Comment: A significant $F$ statistic alone would indicate $A$ truly has a component that lies in the space generated by the other variables.  Examining the p-values is unnecessary and can be misleading.  For instance, all p-values could be very high--near $1.0$--and yet $A$ would still be strongly correlated with the group of variables.